# How to randomize order by sets in r?

Tags: r, random-generation

I need to randomize a list of words by sets. I have  a list of 5 pairs of words and in each pair there are two words: one word in position 1 (1w1) and another word in position 2 (1w2). These pairs are intervened with four other items.

```
list<-c("1w1", "2w1", "3w1", "4w1", "5w1", "1w2", "2w2", "3w2", "4w2", "5w2")
> list<-data.frame(list)
> list
   list
1   1w1
2   2w1
3   3w1
4   4w1
5   5w1
6   1w2
7   2w2
8   3w2
9   4w2
10  5w2
```

I need to randomize this list by preserving position (1w1 should always be before 1w2) and interval between the pairs (4 items). 
Can any one help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work...

```
 word = c("1w1", "2w1", "3w1", "4w1", "5w1", "1w2", "2w2", "3w2", "4w2", "5w2")
 list = data.frame(id = seq(1,10),
              word = word)
 idx = sample(seq(1,5),5)
 idx2 = idx + 5 # preserving distance
 # idx2 = sample(seq(6,10),5) # not preserving distance

 as.vector(list$word[c(idx,idx2)])
 [1] "2w1" "1w1" "4w1" "3w1" "5w1" "2w2" "1w2" "4w2" "3w2" "5w2"
```

Comment: It works. Can I also melt two columns by preserving the interval?